# slice function in JavaScript not working for pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, slice

I'm doing a Todo Application using Angularjs. I tried using pagination which will display only 5 todos per page. I could add pagination but the slice function is not working on the todos list.

It says slice function on undefined. I got the reason for its undefined behaviour. It is because the todo list is not in the scope and I somehow need to bring the todo list out, so that it will be available to the next function. But with zero success I could make it possible.

This is my controller code:

```
todoApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$filter', 'Todos', function($scope, $filter, Todos) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.count = 0;

    $scope.filteredTodos = [];   
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.numPerPage = 5;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;

    // GET =====================================================================
    // when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
    // use the service to get all the todos
    //$scope.todos = [];
    Todos.get()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
            // for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                //$scope.todos.push(data[i]);
            //}
            $scope.loading = false;
            angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo){
                todo.formattedCreatedOn = $filter('date')(new Date(todo.createdOn),'MMM dd, yyyy  -  hh:mm a');
            });
        });

     $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage);
        var end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

        $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
    });
}]);
```

The $scope.todos, I need to somehow put it outside its current scope. So it is not available for the `function $scope.todos.slice(begin,end)`.

Other thing is that the $watch function is called before the todos list is build. It is because by the time the service retrieves the todos from db the $watch is already being called on list with length 0 and hence not working out further.

I even tried using the code in [this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/FUeWwDu0XzO51lyLAEIA?p=preview).

Comment: Why are you watching those variables? I don't get it. Just add a normal scope method which is called once you click on the paginator directive.

Comment: I did it as shown in the plunker link I have just attached. But it wasn't successful. Please help me more on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get it working by first defining $scope.todos (there is a comment-line, why is it commented out?) and then by checking whether the boundaries "begin" and "end" are within the size of your todos-array. You might receive a number of elements which is not dividable by your numPerPage, so in any case you will have to check whether end is beyond the size of your array and set it accordingly if so.

```
$scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage);
    var end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

    if(end>=$scope.todos.length)
      end = $scope.todos.length-1;

    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
});
```

Let me know if that did the trick.

Cheers, Kristof

Comment: Okay, what's happening? Does it still complain about $scope.todos being undefined in $scope.watch?

Comment: No, it does not complain me about that. But it is not displaying any record at all only the pagination stuff like : First Previous 1 Next Last. Thats it.

Comment: I guess this is because currentPage + numPerPage do not change after retrieving the data (which is asynchronous). Did you try changing these parameter from your ui? Maybe install ng-inspector for chrome to look at your scopes.

Answer (score 0):

If you display a list of Todos, I presume there's a ng-repeat in your template. You might be interested in limitTo filter, which is a preferable way of filtering data for display purposes:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

example:

```js
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('TodosController',
function TodosController($scope) {
 $scope.todos = [
  {name:"todo1"},
  {name:"todo2"},
  {name:"todo3"},
  {name:"todo4"},
  {name:"todo5"},
  {name:"todo6"},
  {name:"todo7"}
 ];
  
 /* Rows per page */
 $scope.limit = 3;
 /* We start displaying at item 0 */
 $scope.begin = 0;
}
                                      
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TodosController">
  
 todos (page {{begin/limit}}):
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="todo in todos | limitTo:limit : begin">{{todo}}</li>
 </ul>

 <button ng-click="begin = 0">&lt;&lt;</button>
 <button ng-click="begin = begin>=limit ? begin - limit:0">&lt; previous page</button>
 <button ng-click="begin = begin + limit">next page &gt; </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Here it will go beyond the limit of my todos, won't it? Like consider your case itself, there are 7 todos which will fit in 2 pages 5 each. If I try going on next page it will go and show me nothing, Right?? Correct me if I m wrong. And if it is so, how to stop it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. This is just a demo of "LimitTo", an incomplete pagination system. I'll edit it a bit. Anywayn using limitTo, you can roll up your own pagination system by just modifying the 'begin' model.

Comment: I tried this way as shown by you. But it is just changing the page number : `todos (page 0)` over here, but not the records it is showing on the page. That is, only the page number is changing and not the records in the list on the click of next and previous.

Comment: That works well on my side with Chrome 45.0.2454.101 or FF42: If I click "Next page", I get litterraly this: `todos (page 1):
{"name":"todo4"}
{"name":"todo5"}
{"name":"todo6"}
`

Comment: I've edited the example so you can't go to negatives pages, which displayed a strange behaviour

Comment: Yes, your example works on my chrome as well. But it is not working for my example somehow.

Comment: It is not changing the records on the page. I think the buttons and the records are not getting linked to each other.

Comment: I updated you plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ORWCaME9FwqpP4xzsUuc?p=preview

It needs a recent version of angular though, because limitTo API has changed since 1.2.

Comment: and, if needs be, you can polyfill your limitTo filter, the code is'nt complicated: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/limitTo.js

Comment: Thanks BiAiB for your solution in which you changed the plunker code. But I'm facing the same problem. The records are not changing on click of page numbers. It is showing me same records for page 1, 2.

Comment: Is it because I'm calling service to get data from db server unlike you creating data there itself and just display it?

Comment: Pagination is working fine with all the ways you suggested since I see the current page changing. But the records on change of page are not changing at all.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code :

```
todoApp.filter('limitFromTo', function(){
    return function(input, from, to){
        return (input != undefined)? input.slice(from, to) : '';
    }
});
```

and used this filter over here :

```
ng-repeat="todo in todos | limitFromTo:(currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage:(currentPage*itemsPerPage)"
```

Instead of using limitTo function which was using parameters like `itemsPerPage` and `(currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage`, I used the **limitFromTo**, my own filter which will have two offsets in the array like if the currentPage is 1 then it will show records from 0-5, for 2 6-10 and so on. The **limitTo filter** has parameters like ***how many records one wants to show*** and ***from which index or offset***, which is not what I wanted and hence used limitFromTo according to my needs. And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `$scope.$watch` inside the `.success` callback:

```
Todos.get()
    .success(function(data) {

        $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
          var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage);
          var end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

          $scope.filteredTodos = data.slice(begin, end);
        });
    });
});
```